# Removing commas and quotes from numeric fields in csv file using SSIS

Tags: csv, ssis

I am creating SSIS package which reads data from a csv file and stores in SQL Server database. There are a few numeric fields in the csv files.
They sometimes contain value like **"1,008.54"**

How do I remove the quotes and comma from the value?

I have successfully separated the rows with this kind of data by using **Conditional Split Transformation**.
(SUBSTRING([Column 9],1,1) == "\"")

After this, I tried using **Derived Column Transformation** to REPLACE comma and quotes with empty string. But it is not working.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your sample value "1,008.54" in a Data Flow where my source was:

`SELECT '"1,008.54"'  AS [Column]`

I then placed the following expression in a Derived Column Transformation (imitating what you did attempted)

`REPLACE(REPLACE(Column,",",""),"\"","")`

and successfully achieved your request:   *Using Derived Column Transformation, REPLACE comma and quotes with empty string.*

Here's the result as presented by a data viewer after the Derived Column Transformation:

```
Column  Derived Column 1
"1,008.54"  1008.54
```