# Remove commas or change commas to spaces SSIS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis

SSIS 2010

How do you please stop the commas or delete the commas..when sending data from a dB source SQL to a flat file txt file please

Just using col1 col2 col3 as column names

Table name is Recipe

Chicken,mushroom,cheese

I wish to have

Chicken mushroom cheese

Basically a space instead of comma

Please help?

Comment: Use a [Derived Column transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) with an expression that uses [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replace-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017), eg `REPLACE(somColumn, "," ," ")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing commas and quotes from numeric fields in csv file using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800533/removing-commas-and-quotes-from-numeric-fields-in-csv-file-using-ssis)

Comment: I have tried this. Where in the package exactly do you add the dirived column..as I added it .and the txt file still has commas.

Comment: Between source and target. Remember to write the *new* column to the target, not the source column

Answer (score 1):

Just go to advance properties...and manually change each column delimiter ..as blank or just hit space bar..and it works

Thanks team for advice..x